# Why is it that my UITableViewController setEditing:animated: method is not called?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview

I must be doing stupid, but I can't see what: my `UITableViewController` subclass is never called when the edit button of my navigation is pressed.

What could be causing that?

My view hierarchy is loaded from a Nib file and put inside a popover. The [+] button is connected to the `insertNewObject` action of my `UITableViewController` subclass. It works fine.

The [Edit] button however has no action to connect to. The doc says it will automatically call the `setEditing:animated:` method of the view controller, which I override.

The nib file is set up pretty much as usual AFAICT. And in fact, I'm not sure what additional detail I can give that would suggest my mistake.

What is the control flow from the click on the [Edit] button to the call of the `setEditing:animated` method?

Answer (score 0):

I feel like we must be missing the same thing.

Whatever the case, I made it work by doing the following.

```
IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *editButton;

-(IBAction)editButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self setEditing:YES animated:YES];
}

- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animate
{
    if(self.tableView.isEditing)
    {
        self.editButton.style = UIBarButtonItemStylePlain;
        self.editButton.title = @"Edit";
    }
    else
    {
        //self.editButton.style = UIBarButtonSystemItemDone;
        self.editButton.style = UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit;
        self.editButton.title = @"Done";
    }

    // Toggle table view state
    [super setEditing:!self.tableView.isEditing animated:animate];
}
```

I hooked the editButton up to the button I added to the nav bar and it's action to the editButtonPressed IBAction. After doing that my setEditing: is called (obviously) and the super call toggles the table view's editing state.

I'd like to use the system defined button styles, but the appropriate one is commented out because while it did change style I couldn't figure out how to change the text from "Edit" to "Done" so I had to do it all manually (that only worked if I left the button as Custom and set the style generically). This has the downside of not being localized (for free), etc.